# Easy question regarding RF and ion traps

Tags: charge, frequency, radio, isotopes, ion-traps

I saw this interesting video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-qTa_7FtAA

In this video, from the 8:55 mark to 11:55, this man explains using unique frequencies for each element(?) with a unique m/z to only leave behind elements with a specific m/z within an ion trap. Please view the video for context also.

If this is the case, since isotopes of the same element also have a differing mass (and subsequent differing m/z), could this method be used for isotope enrichment of Magnesium-25 while excluding Mg-24 and Mg-26?

Thank you.

Comment: Good question. In minute 13:20h he shows a diagramme which gives the sensitivity as sufficient to distinguish single atom masses - thus it probably is just a matter of patience, feeding enough new material and proper operation

Comment: @planetmaker Thank you so much! I guess all that is left is some experimentation for me.

Comment: "all that is left" can be enough for a whole scientific career :P

Comment: Have you gotten this to work?

Comment: @Alex It depends, why do you ask? Send a direct message if possible.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/140565/board-for-ion-trap-discussion?tab=general